# Jetpack Compose - Reveal animation with resizing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

By using this code

```
val composableHeight = 200.dp
var composableWidthPx by remember { mutableStateOf(1000f) }
val composableWidth = with(LocalDensity.current) { composableWidthPx.toDp() }
val draggableState = rememberDraggableState(onDelta = {
    composableWidthPx += it
})
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(composableWidth)
        .height(composableHeight)
        .padding(48.dp)
        .draggable(draggableState, Orientation.Horizontal)
        .background(Color.Red)
) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.requiredSize(100.dp),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

I get the following result

[image]

What I want instead is for the `Icon` to stay in a fixed position, with a fixed size, and if I slide over the Icon, I want the respective portion to be hidden. So, that basically would be a reveal animation.

Some thoughts on how I could achieve it?

(You may also come up with a better title for the question.)

Edit:

Some pictures with the wanted result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So what you want is when dragging the red box make the "+" smaller? Or what?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I want it to stay the same size, but dissapear as I drag the right side over it.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with something in which I used `clipToBounds` (thanks Pylyp) and `offset`.

```
val composableHeight = 100.dp
var composableWidthPx by remember { mutableStateOf(1000f) }
val composableWidth = with(LocalDensity.current) { composableWidthPx.toDp() }
val draggableState = rememberDraggableState(onDelta = {
    composableWidthPx += it
})
val iconSize = remember { 100.dp }
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(48.dp)
        .width(composableWidth)
        .height(composableHeight)
        .draggable(draggableState, Orientation.Horizontal)
        .background(Color.Red)
        .clipToBounds()
) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier
            .requiredSize(iconSize)
            .offset(
                maxOf(0.dp, (iconSize - composableWidth) / 2)
            ),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

[image]

If someone can come up with something better, please do so.